# Print function not working Python 3.3

Tags: python, printing, syntax

When I typed tried to run this:
`print('What is your name?')`
it said `print` was invalid syntax.

Comment: can you show the complete traceback? That code alone is not invalid syntax. Maybe you are doing something else.

Comment: What is your exact code? That works fine for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. On SO, the quality of answers often depend upon the quality of the question. One mark of an excellent questions is a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please reduce your original program to the shortest program that still produces the error. Copy-paste that **entire** that program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The preceding line has some error on it. A typical error that could produce this message is a missing parenthesis.

Sample:

```
f(1,2,3
print('What is your name?')
```